# CoffeeScript - simple loop doesn't execute as I think it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I am too new at javascript .. and have a problem with a simple coffee-script.

Script monitors 2 fields on a form and updates a third if the either of them changes.
There "n" rows of the same type in the form.
 here is the code

```
    line_pre = "#po_polines_attributes_"
    watched  = [ "_qty", "_unit_price"]
    UpdateTotal = (ln)  ->
        jQuery  ->
          e1 = line_pre + ln +  watched[0]·
          e2 = line_pre + ln +  watched[1]
          new_total = $(e1).val()*$(e2).val()
          res = line_pre + ln + "_total_price"
          $(res).val(new_total)
     #   
     for indx in [0, 1, 2]
        do  ->  
           for w_fld  in watched
              do ->
                jQuery ->
                   $(line_pre + indx + w_fld).focusout ->
                      UpdateTotal(indx)
```

Code runs but only updates the last row of the data when qty or u_p are changed. 
I can't figure out why.

Also .. can anyone suggest how to find # of elements containing a string in jQuery/coffee
$("input[name~='search_str']").length() doesn't work .. it appears that the returned element doesn't have "length/size" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do`s are missing something: the loop values as arguments.

The function wrapper that `do` provides in something like this:

```
for i in a
  do -> ...
```

doesn't do much since the `do`'s function will still be sharing the same `i` variable just like this JavaScript does:

```
for(i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
  (function() {
    ...
  })();
```

But, if the `do` function gets `i` as an argument:

```
for i in a
  do (i) -> ...
```

then everything changes and you start doing what `do` is intended to do:

```
for(i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
  (function(i) {
    ...
  })(i);
```

Notice how this `do (i) ->` version forces `i` to be evaluated when calling the function so that you're no longer working with the shared `i`.

Applying this to your loops yields:

```
for indx in [0, 1, 2]
  do (indx) ->
    for w_fld  in watched
      do (w_fld) ->
        jQuery ->
          $(line_pre + indx + w_fld).focusout ->
            UpdateTotal(indx)
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response and full explanation -